# Convert a/b string to float in pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe like this:

```
        score  year
         5/5   2019
         1/2   2018
          A    2019
```

I want to convert score from string to float like 5/5=1, 1/2=0.5, I tried to_numeric but as my values are in a/b form it's returning me none. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.eval`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.eval.html) with `try-except` statement:

```
def func(x):
    try:
        return pd.eval(x)
    except Exception:
        #for return original
        return x
        #for return None
        #return None

df['new'] = df['score'].apply(func)
print (df)
  score  year  new
0   5/5  2019    1
1   1/2  2018  0.5
2     A  2019    A
```

If there is only division is faster solution from @Goyo, thank you:

```
import operator

def func(x):
    try:
        return operator.truediv(*map(int, x.split('/')))
    except Exception:
        #for return original
        return x
        #for return None
        #return None
```

Comment: Can i do anything to return any character as None too like A will be set to None

Comment: @BarotShalin - sure, only change `return x` to `return None`

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much!

Comment: `operator.truediv(*map(int, x.split('/')))` is one order of magnitude faster in my tests and it won't run arbitrary code.